# HTML Form Validation in PHP.

Tags: php, html, css

I am completely brand-new to php and after researching about it I am still unable to find the appropriate answer. As I am trying to get my form validated with php and the error messages customised with CSS.

My HTML code is :

```
<div class="container">
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
        <select type="dropdown" name="contact" placeholder="Age">
            <option placeholder="australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Talk To Us" style="height:200px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My CSS is on pastebin below:

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/R2JiMK3d)

[image: Form I wish Validated]

P.S I am also thinking about putting the for validation code into a separate file and that file will be saved into the includes folder.

Comment: Can you post the code on `action_page.php` please?

Comment: I just put that their so i knew what what their. I don't actually have a file called that yet, because i don't know where to begin on form validation or processing

Comment: Your question is too broad. Follow some PHP tutorials and come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The data will be available in the php-script through the $_GET global variable as an array. Each input is an item in this array, e.g. $_GET["name"].
The script `action_page.php` could look something like this (this is just a beginning...):

```
<?php
//Test the input, for example like this:
if(empty($_GET["name"])) $error="You need to provide a name";
if(strpos($_GET["email"],"@")==0) $error="The e-mail is not valid"; //Of course you could test for a lot more, for example using regular expressions

//Now you can build your response to the user
if($error) {
   echo ("<h1>Error</h1>".$error);
}
include("form.html"); //If you want to show the same form again.
```

You could also include the errors more integrated in the form - but then you would need to integrate PHP into the HTML.

You will find good documentation at http://www.php.net, and http://w3schools.com/ has a lot of good stuff as well.

Comment: Undefined variable, followed by the location of the file

Comment: This is not an error, but a notification from php. You will want to set error_reporting to something less strict in php.ini (on Linux it is in /etc/php/7.2/ - on windows, you need to search the internet to find out where it is).

Comment: @KyleLogan $error needs to be set to an empty string at the top of the file, otherwise if the two conditions aren't met, $error hasn't been initialized.